# Can someone explain Bootstrap's Collapse code?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was digging through Bootstrap source code, specifically the bootstrap-collapse.js v2.3.1

On line 157 where it does:

```
$(document).on('click.collapse.data-api', '[data-toggle=collapse]', function (e) { .. })
```

Can someone please explain what that does. I've been using jQuery for a while now but I've never seen it used that way.

Thanks SO!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/ The documentation explains it right at the top.

Answer (score 6):

This attaches a delegated event listener to `document`, which is listening for the `click.collapse.data-api` event (a [namespaced event](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/)) to be triggered from any elements where the `data-toggle` attribute equals `collapse`.

Comment: `click.collapse.data-api` is a `click` event with two namespaces; it's not a custom event, just custom namespaces.

Comment: Thanks @zzzzBov, I didn't know about event namespacing. I updated my answer.

Comment: Great! And welcome to StackOverflow! It's customary here to upvote and accept an answer if it meets your needs. Thanks and good luck!

Comment: @Colinexl Thanks for trying :) You should still be able to accept the answer. Accepting will also bump up your reputation as well :)